# Using more than two I2C OLED displays on a Pico

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, python, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a Raspberry Pi Pico running CircuitPython and I use the adafruit_ssd1306 library to drive SSD1306 OLED displays.

This works very well for two displays, but when adding the third it doesn't update the third. If I comment out the code for the second display the third works, and if I don't unplug the power after updating the code, they can all be powered at the same time, so it's not a voltage/current issue. This is an issue regardless of which GPIO pins I use.

Here's the code I'm using alongside the [font5x8.bin](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_framebuf/issues/10) mentioned in an issue on CircuitPython:

```python
import adafruit_ssd1306, board, busio

display_one = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 32, busio.I2C(scl=board.GP1, sda=board.GP0))

display_one.fill(0)
display_one.text("Display One", 30,12, True)
display_one.show()

display_two = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 32, busio.I2C(scl=board.GP3, sda=board.GP2))

display_two.fill(0)
display_two.text("Display Two", 30,12, True)
display_two.show()

display_three = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 32, busio.I2C(scl=board.GP15, sda=board.GP14))

display_three.fill(0)
display_three.text("Display Three", 30,12, True)
display_three.show()
```

EDIT: I also tried releasing the displays using `displayio.release_displays()`.

Comment: My _guess_ is you don't have enough memory on the Pico to do have three full objects. I don't expect CircuitPython to be very space efficient. GCC's `size` would normally be what you use to find usage.

Comment: @awjlogan That would be my guess to, I tried to use only one variable and overwrite it for every display but that didn't make a difference. How do you suppose i'd go about confirming size is the issue with GCC?

Comment: No idea about the CircuitPython toolchain, to be honest, sorry - I don't consider Python to be suitable for microcontrollers (rightly or wrongly). You should end up with an ELF file, which you can then use "normal" tools on (lots of questions all over SE).

Answer (score 3):

Solved using a multiplexer (74HC4051) and a logic level shifter from 3.3 V to 5 V.

Comment: Thanks for following up - could you post a schematic of what you've done? It would help anyone else who comes across this :)

Answer (score 2):

There are only two I2C controllers, so only two pairs of GPIO pins can be used at one time.